# LaTeX characters: dots and overlines combined

Tags: characters, accents

For alphabets with dots one has `ö=\"o`, but I would like to introduce another horizontal line just above the two dots. The command `\=\"o` doesn't yield the sought result.

Comment: Did you try `\={\"o}`? Writing `\=o` is actually an abbreviated form of `\={o}` which works because there's only a token. You want to put the bar above the whole `\"o` (which should be `\"{o}`, but works also without braces for the same reason).

Comment: No matter how many braces I put, the same result -- the bar is stubbornly put *before* the \"o.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, which for a Finn should be always the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, superimposing accents is not always easy; even the advice of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` doesn't give the expected result. Here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\tbar}[1]{\mbox{%
  \sbox0{#1}\sbox2{\={}}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth\raise\dimexpr\ht0-\ht2+.25ex\box2 \hidewidth\cr#1\cr}}}

\begin{document}
\tbar{\"o}\={\"o}
\end{document}
```

I've put next the result of superimposing the accent. Act on `.25ex` for changing the height of the bar.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this worked even with [T2A]{fontenc}, that I had to have for certain reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@egreg's answer wasn't working for me on XeLaTeX, but I found something that works OK.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
addi\lapbox[0pt]{-.4em}{\raisebox{.2em}{\={\space}}}c-\v{e}re
\end{document}
```

Comment: Provided the font support for combining characters is good, directly typing `ȫ` should do (it is U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS followed by U+0304 COMBINING MACRON). See [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Q9W.png) obtained with Linux Libertine.

Comment: On the other hand, your code with just adding `fontspec` and compiling with XeLaTeX gives a bar extending over the “d”.